# Regex Nested Shortcode Does Not Work

Tags: php, regex, nested, shortcode

Can someone tell me why this does not work ? - https://regex101.com/r/hJ5zN6/11

Test string:

```
[test][dzspgb_container][dzspgb_row][dzspgb_row_part part="1.4"][dzspgb_element text="whwaha" type_element="text"][/dzspgb_element][dzspgb_element text="test" type_element="text"][/dzspgb_element][/dzspgb_row_part][dzspgb_row_part part="1.4"][/dzspgb_row_part][dzspgb_row_part part="1.4"][/dzspgb_row_part][dzspgb_row_part part="1.4"][/dzspgb_row_part][/dzspgb_row][dzspgb_container]test second[/dzspgb_container][/dzspgb_container][/thisbreaks]
```

Test regex:

```
*\[dzspgb_container(.*?)](.*?)\[\/dzspgb_container\](?!\s*\[\/)*
```

If we remove **`[/thisbreaks]`** from the string, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the negative lookahead assertion at the end. I suggest you to remove that lookahead and use a greedy regex pattern like below.

```
\[dzspgb_container(.*?)](.*)\[\/dzspgb_container\]
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hJ5zN6/12)

`(?!\s*\[\/)` asserts that the match won't be followed by (*zero or more space characters and a `[` symbol*)

Comment: or a non-greedy regex `\[dzspgb_container(.*?)](.*?)\[\/dzspgb_container\]`, since i don't know what exactly you want.

Comment: if there is another element it will take that too - https://regex101.com/r/hJ5zN6/13